# 'Rotating' axes along a ball joint.

Tags: geometry

Suppose we have rotate a coordinate system over some angle $\theta$. Then we can use rotation matrices to express the new axes in terms of the old axes. What if we don't have a rotating joint, but a ball joint like in your shoulder. We can express the position of that joint by a point in $S^2$, is there a way to express the new axes in terms of the old ones and the point on $S^2$?

Answer (score 1):

The rotated axes cannot be expressed in terms of a point on $S^2$ (and the old axes) *alone*. Further rotations around a vector passing through this point will move the rotated axes, while keeping the point in place. Imaging twisting your straight arm, while pointing into the same direction.